# Strange behavior with a project in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

I am migrating a project from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE2.

I am still working on it but when I run the project in **Delphi XE2**, it stopped in a function which calls a unit from a third party component. This unit was not initialized so I expected this error.

However, when I compiled the project in **Delphi 7** and I got to the part where it should break like in XE2, it works normally. Therefore, I proceed to inspect this unit in the project, when i try to compile now, with the unit *opened* in the IDE. it show this message.

***Field FormPropiedadesElemento.SpinVector does not have a corresponding component. Remove the declaration?***

After I click "NO", the project runs but now stops in the same part as the Delphi XE2 project.

This problem only happens in Delphi 7 when I am seeing the code from this unit.

Any idea what could it be or how to solve it?

Comment: Add the corresponding component in the dfm.

Comment: Add the component to a temporary project and configure it, then copy its object definition from the dfm to the dfm of the failing unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, this happens because you don't have the appropriate design-time package for that component installed in the IDE.

What the error means is that you have a field in the IDE-managed part of your form declaration that does not have a corresponding component in the dfm file.

Comment: Do you have the design-time package for the component installed? That is, do you have the component on your palette?

Comment: No, I do not have it.

Comment: Then you will not be able to edit (open) the form in the IDE. If you have the source code for the supporting unit, you can probably still compile and run the project.

Comment: You can still edit the pascal source code, but not the corresponding dfm file. If you have switched the dfm to use text, you can edit that text directly, *if you know what you are doing*.